# jvisualvm doesn't exclude certain methods from CPU profiling

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile an application with jvisualvm. The application consists of a loop, in which data is loaded from a database and then some complex calculations are performed on the data. When a set of data is processed, the next set is loaded and calculated.

When I start my application and attach jvisualvm, I set up a filter on the CPU profiling page ("Sart profiling from classes" and "Do not profile classes"), since I am not interested in anything that relates to the database access, and other input/output related stuff.

The filter works - almost. My problem is, that the profiler reports most of the time is spent in `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run()`, even though sun.* is entered into the "Do not profile classes" filter. This is the only method in sun.* appearing in my profiling results.

Has anyone seen this before and knows how to get rid of it? Problem is, all other methods show up only with tiny amounts (<1%) in the "Self Time" column, most are displayed with 0%.

The jvisualvm version used is 1.3.2.

Thanks in advance,
Axel

Comment: Don't look at "Self Time". [It's practically meaningless.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

Comment: Interesting link, but given that the only columns to display are "Self Time", "Self Time [%]", and "Invocations" there's not much left to look at... :-)

Comment: There must be a way to get inclusive time. It might be called "cumulative" or "total" time.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like most of the time is spent waiting from the database. If you want to profile the rest of the stuff, you can either

- stub the database so that it returns quickly (thus making the rest of your code take most of the time), or
- use a better profiler such as YourKit or JProfiler (paid, definitely support what you want) or TPTP (free, but I'm not sure how powerful it us)

Comment: Well then I'll go with your first suggestion. I have used TPTP before, but it isn't available any more Indigo. If nothing helps, I think I'll have to keep a separate Helios installation for profiling.

Comment: [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) is paid, correct but it has ~2-weeks trial period. I used its trial to profile an urgent problem - after that _trial_ I was more than happy to get paid version.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck 'Profile new Runnables' on the CPU profiling page.
To answer your other question with "Self Time" - you need to take a [CPU snapshot](http://visualvm.java.net/snapshots.html) of profiled data. The snapshot contains total method time info.